# Yii2: How to change style of excel sheet with kartik export widget (ExportMenu)

Tags: yii2, export-to-excel, kartik-v

I use the kartik export widget (ExportMenu) and I want to change the style in the excel sheet. I want a table without border. I have tried this:

```
$style = [
    'borders' => [
        'outline' => [
            'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_NONE,
        ],
        'inside' => [
            'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_NONE,
        ]
    ],
];

$exportMenu = ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
                'exportConfig' => [
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_TEXT => false,
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_HTML => false,
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => false,
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_CSV => false,
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL => false,
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL_X => $style,
                 ],
        ]);

    echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
        'panel' => [
            'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
            'heading' => '',
        ],
        'exportContainer' => [
            'class' => 'btn-group mr-2'
        ],
        'toolbar' => [
            $exportMenu,
            'options' => ['class' => 'btn-group']
        ],
    ]);
```

I have read the documentation (http://demos.krajee.com/export) and actually it should work in this way. But nothing changes. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem as follows:

```
$exportMenu = ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider], 
    'autoXlFormat'=> false,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
            'exportConfig' => [
                ExportMenu::FORMAT_TEXT => false,
                ExportMenu::FORMAT_HTML => false,
                ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => false,
                ExportMenu::FORMAT_CSV => false,
                ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL => false,
             ],
             'boxStyleOptions' => [
                ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL_X => [
                    'borders' => [
                        'outline' => [
                            'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_NONE,
                         ],
                         'inside' => [
                         'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_NONE,
                         ],
                     ],
                ],
             ],
            'exportContainer' => [
                'class' => 'btn-group mr-2'
            ],
            'dropdownOptions' => [
                'label' => Yii::t('app/importExport', 'Export'),
                'class' => 'btn btn-secondary',
            ],
            'filename' => $dataProviderExport["fileName"],
    ]);
```